# How to calculate perimeter of shape in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, gis, geospatial

Very simple question, very hard to find a good and fast solution.

Is there any implementation how to calculate perimeter of shape saved as spatial data in MySQL?

As for now in 5.7/8.0 there is a function ST_Area, Centroid etc but no Perimeter like in e.g. QGis/ArcGIS/other. How to calculate perimeter of shapes saved as:

```
POLYGON((-0.064064467695394 51.517842990224,-0.064052072253155   51.517846382663,-0.064060161846309 51.517859555443,-0.064067607477908 51.517870919076,-0.064150020271406 51.518000873356,-0.064212111950441 51.517981215205,-0.064106051285605 51.517831086958,...etc
```

in PURE MySQL 5.7+ (procedure/function) or eventually MySQL with PHP?

Shapes are small enough to not to use any spherical distance, so I'm assuming, that in this case Earth is flat :)

Thank you for any useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to do this in PHP. Not to say it can't be done in MySQL, of course.

This is my PHP solution:

```
function perimeterFromValue($value) {
    $points = array_map(
        function($pair) {
            return preg_split('#\\s+#', $pair, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        },
        explode(',', $value)
    );
    $start  = array_shift($points);
    // Make the perimeter close onto itself (if it is already, remove this line)
    $points[] = $start;
    return array_reduce($points, function($carry, $item) use(&$start) {
        $carry += hypot($item[0]-$start[0], $item[1]-$start[1]);
        $start = $item;
        return $carry;
    }, 0);
}
```

It splits the string into comma-separated pairs, then separates each pair on the space(s) in the middle. From there on, it uses Pythagoras' theorem in a reduce loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function as below and pass parameter you want to pass.

Suppose you want to calculate perimeter of square of 4 length.

You can get value as below.

```
$$ delimiter 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `schema_name`.`perimeter` ;
$$ delimiter 
CREATE FUNCTION `schema_name`.`perimeter` (radius_length INT,shape_name varchar(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
BEGIN
  DECLARE RETURN_VAL INT;
  IF shape_name = 'SQUARE' THEN
   SET RETURN_VAL = 4*radius_length;
  END IF;
  IF shape_name = 'CIRCLE' THEN
   SET RETURN_VAL = PI()*radius_length*radius_length;
  END IF;
RETURN RETURN_VAL;
END;
```

**`select schema_name.perimeter(4,'SQUARE');`**

definitely it will help you.

Comment: Squares are different. From triangles (3 nodes) to quite complicated (hundreds of nodes). Sorry I didn't mention, but didn't trealize that is important.